# How to ignore numerous deleted files in git?

Tags: git

I have added a folder containing millions of files with `git add` and deleted them using `git rm -r FolderPath`. Then I commited `git commit` and the object folder size in .git reaches to more than 250mb. So when I try to push the repository, it literally doesn't do the job duo to large number of files.
I tried many ways like `git add -u`, `git gc`, `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`, etc. but non of them solved the problem.

Finally I deleted the object folder and everything messed up. So I can neither push or pull.

Anyone know a simple way to avoid these scenarios?

Comment: Can you go to the older commit? before the mistake? and the delete the once with the mistake

Comment: Possibly related: [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository). The question could be clearer, though. Can you edit your question to clarify whether the files you added and removed were ever committed and whether you want to keep them in the history or not? I'd also keep searching: there arelikely question swith answers that are close enough that you can solve this without waiting for someone to answer this question.

Comment: @chwarr I edited the question. But the provided solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is: Don't put in commits you don't want to put in.

Every commit *adds to* the repository.  A repository is nothing more than a large collection of commits.

All commits are completely, totally read-only.  No part of any commit can ever be changed.

Every commit has a full snapshot of all of its files.  If the file in the snapshot is the same as some previous file in some previous snapshot, Git can and does *re-use* the previous file.  If the snapshot doesn't have some previous file, it just doesn't have the file.  That doesn't change the previous snapshot.  You're still just *adding* a snapshot: it's just one that does not have the file.

It *is* possible to *remove* a commit, sort of.  To do this, though, you must remove *every subsequent (descendant) commit as well*, because part of each commit is the commit-hash-ID of its *previous* commit, which must exist.  So if you put in a big commit by mistake, it's easy to remove it when it's still the *last* commit.  But if you add more commits on top of it, you now have to remove every commit from the bad one on.

I'll leave the rest to [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1256452)